# Problema ao inserir texto em uma div com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo trocar o conteudo html de uma div, colocando a 1 opção de um array de elementos, mas quando faço o seguinte código não acontece nada:

```
<script>
    var players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6', 'player7', 'player8'];

    var teste = document.getElementById('jog1');

    teste.innerHTML = players[0];

</script>


    <div class="player top win" id ='jog1'>
      boo
    </div>
```

Ao acessar o index.html, ao invés de "boo", deveria estar "player1" mas continua como boo. Outra dúvida, tem como eu tirar esse "boo" do codigo e somente pedir para adicionar direto o 'player1' na pagina html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente não esperando o documento estar pronto e carregado, e já está tentando obter o elemento e trocar seu conteúdo, tento fazer isso por exemplo no evento `onload` do body:

```js
var players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6', 'player7', 'player8'];

window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    var teste = document.getElementById('jog1');
    teste.innerHTML = players[0];
  });
```

```html
<div class="player top win" id ='jog1'>
      boo
    </div>
```

Comment: obrigado, deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Neste seu exemplo, bastaria colocar o script depois do código html, desta forma:

```html
<div class="player top win" id ='jog1'>
  boo
</div>

<script>
    var players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4', 'player5', 'player6', 'player7', 'player8'];

    var teste = document.getElementById('jog1');

    teste.innerHTML = players[0];

</script>
```

O navegador executa os códigos na medida em que lê, e, em seu código, você tenta localizar, no script, um elemento que o navegador ainda não interpretou, por isso nada ocorre (na verdade ele gera um erro).

Quanto a segunda dúvida, não compreendi bem, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Obrigado! 

A segunda duvida era se o "boo" seria obrigatorio, mas fiz o teste e se vc deixar a div vazia, o "player1" ainda fica lá!